# Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.2)

Tags: android-studio, flutter, dart

I got following error when I run "**flutter doctor --android-licenses**" command

```
A newer version of the Android SDK is required. To update, run:
/Users/taleb/Library/Android/sdk/tools/bin/sdkmanager --update
```

notice:

```
 * my android SDK is updated
 * I added all of the paths to 'bash_profile' (mac)
```

this is my '**bash_profile**'

```
export PATH="$PATH:/⁨Users⁩/taleb⁩/Library/Android⁩/sdk⁩/platform-tools"
export ANDROID_HOME=$HOME/Library/Android/sdk
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools⁩
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools⁩
export PATH="$PATH:/Users/taleb/Developer/flutter/bin"
```

I also run "**sdkmanager --update**" command but I got the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlSchema
    at com.android.repository.api.SchemaModule$SchemaModuleVersion.<init>(SchemaModule.java:156)
    at com.android.repository.api.SchemaModule.<init>(SchemaModule.java:75)
    at com.android.sdklib.repository.AndroidSdkHandler.<clinit>(AndroidSdkHandler.java:81)
    at com.android.sdklib.tool.sdkmanager.SdkManagerCli.main(SdkManagerCli.java:73)
    at com.android.sdklib.tool.sdkmanager.SdkManagerCli.main(SdkManagerCli.java:48)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:602)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
    ... 5 more
```

Answer (score 4):

Open android studio, tools >> SDK manager >> SDK Platforms and then download the platform that has API Level of (29) and then click Apply. After that run `flutter doctor`

[image: screenshot of SDK manager]